# Advice on how to find health datasets in .csv

Tags: r, csv, dataset

I am teaching some biomedical engineering students how to handle datasets but I would like to do it with health-related topics.

I've already checked the available datasets in R base and got some of them for any students but they are not enough for my whole class.

There is no need for code here, just searching for some advice.

I'd thank if any of you people let me know where to find health datasets available for learning with any structure: time series, unstructured data, data frames with categorical and numerical variables, longitudinal survey data, etc.

Comment: One of my students is particularly interested in depression data, thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this will be voted to close as it is quite off topic here. If you'd be interested in gene expression data in depression www.stanleygenomics.org has gene expression datasets from depression and bipolar disorder patients. They provide the data in TSV format but I assume it shouldn't matter too much

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right site to ask about finding datasets since that's not a specific programming question. It might be better to try some place like [opendata.se] or maybe even [stats.se]. Be sure to check what they consider to be on-topic before posting there.

Comment: I did not know it was inappropriate, so thanks for answering, useful feedback, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at the [ICPSR](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/content/about/)
It is a

> An international consortium of more than 750 academic institutions and research organizations[...]ICPSR maintains a data archive of more than 250,000 files of research in the social and behavioral sciences. It hosts 21 specialized collections of data in education, aging, criminal justice, substance abuse, terrorism, and other fields.

You can download many datasets of very different topics including many related to [health](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/search/studies?CLASSIF_FACET=ICPSR.IX.).

**EDIT**

Regarding Mental Health there is the *National Survey on Drug Use and Health*.
You can find datasets at the ICPSR or in the [SAMSHA website](https://www.samhsa.gov/data/all-reports?f[]=field_issues_conditions_disorder:6553&f[]=field_issues_conditions_disorder:6542)

Comment: It's awesome!! Thanks a lot @c1au61o_HH